# Refresh Token Issue

Tags: react-native, aws-amplify

I am using AWS amplify SDK for React native.

Using the below method in the SDK signing into Cognito user pool.

```
Auth.federatedSignIn(
      COGNITO_SAML_PROVIDER,
      { token: samlToken, expires_at: 0 },
      { email, name: '' },
    );
```

Then retrieving the keys using currentCredentials to access AWS API gateway.

```
credentials = await Auth.currentCredentials();
     const requestTokens = {
       access_key: credentials.accessKeyId,
       secret_key: credentials.secretAccessKey,
       session_token: credentials.sessionToken,
     };
```

Problem:
After idle period of 30 mins the SDK doesn't refresh the session_token and uses the expired token for subsequent request and we run into issue "the security token included in the request is invalid"

Is there a way or some parameter to set in the SDK so that the token gets refreshed periodically?